# Docker doesnt read env file but no error showed

Tags: python, docker, environment-variables

I have a python script with:

```
os.environ["MY_VAR"]
```

The docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: '1'
services:
  webserver:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      MY_VAR: ${MY_VAR}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ADD ./.env ./
RUN pip install -r docker_src/requirements.pip
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

`.env` file

```
# AWS
MY_VAR=home
```

If I do `docker-compose config` the variable appears with the expected value. Then, I run docker docker-compose up -d --build, and I run the python script and it fails returning:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'MY_VAR'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should also use the recent version for docker-compose `version: '3'`, then pass the `MY_VAR`.

```
export MY_VAR=test && docker-compose up
```

When you use

```
    environment:
      MY_VAR: ${MY_VAR}
```

It looking for `MY_VAR` in the host environment variable.

Or if you want to use `.env` then you have sepcify the `env` file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  webserver:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file:
       - .env
```

update:

simple example

```
version: '3'
services:
  webserver:
    image: alpine
    command: printenv
    env_file:
       - .env
```

and .env

```
MY_ENV1=test1
MY_ENV1=test2
```

[image]

Comment: I used the version 3 and the 3.7 to solve the issue and nothing works. Neither the env_file option that you told me. I added a var to dockerfile and that is working, but not in docker-compose.yml

Comment: Still the same. If i use the command:printenv option it shows the value, but when running a script in the docker the os.environ doesn't has the variable